# «И в том числе» — спорный случай или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, союзы

Есть предложение:

```
Здесь, на БАМе, «рыжий дьявол» стал причиной пневмоний, гнойных тонзиллитов, воспалений среднего уха, маститов и в том числе остеомиелитов.
```

У автора не стоит запятая перед "и в том числе". Насколько я понимаю, это присоединительная конструкция. Интересует вопрос: если автор видит здесь однородный ряд, а не присоединительную конструкцию, то запятую, значит, можно не ставить?

Comment: Такое использование не считается нормой.

Comment: Таких примеров не мало, что тогда считать нормой?

Comment: Вот это: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_129

Comment: Там нет примеров с однородным рядом

Comment: Потому что это не норма.

Comment: Не норма строить такие предложения ?

Comment: Если строго, то да. В этом предложении нет общего, в число которого включать.

Comment: Получается, что остеомиелиты являются частным случаем маститов, а это не так. "В том числе" нужно убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашла похожее предложение здесь:
[Д. П. Шраер-Петров. Охота на рыжего дьявола. Роман с микробиологами](http://flibusta.site/b/346263/read) (глава 16).

> В этом повествовании я рассказываю о Рыжем Дьяволе, о стафилококке, хотя все время получается, что свой рассказ перебиваю посторонними вставками.
> <...>
> В течение моей врачебной работы я не раз встречался с гнойными поражениями костной ткани — остеомиелитами. <...>  *Здесь на БАМе Рыжий Дьявол оставался причиной пневмоний, гнойных тонзиллитов, воспалений среднего уха, маститов, остеомиелитов.*

Считаю, что правильно писать без союза. Просто, думаю, на каком-то корректорском этапе были внесены неудачные изменения.

**Особенности**

Распространённая ошибка при использовании данного сочетания — это отсутствие в предложении указания на целое, часть которого уточняется.

Если оборот начинается с союзов «а», «и», то запятая ставится только перед союзом и после оборота.
*Пётр Степанович, любивший танцы, **а в том числе и мазурку,** всегда любовался на молодежь. Они закончили обустраивать дом, **и в том числе** хорошенькую детскую.*

[«В том числе»: запятая нужна или нет?](https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/v-tom-chisle-zapyataya-nuzhna-ili-net#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%20%C2%AB%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%C2%BB%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5.)

Comment: @МиМопи  Интересно, почему Вы не отметили этот ответ? Да и принять его, думаю, тоже можно.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Спасибо за поддержку, Саша! Ну не умею я, как ты, направлять и настаивать. А вот желание отвечать —  крутя последними мозгами, выискивая и сопоставляя, — постепенно пропадает. Ведь непонятно: нужны ответы или нет, полезны или *как*?