# Сравнение или образ действия?

Tags: обстоятельство, сравнение

Объясните мне, глупому, может, я что-то не понимаю. Всегда было правило:

> если оборот можно заменить творительным падежом существительного или
> наречием, то считалось, что мы имеем дело с обстоятельством образа
> действия, а не сравнением.

---

Тренажер подготовки к ОГЭ. Пример: "Взовьется белый дым змеей" — сравнение. Может, вы объясните, почему слово в ТВОРИТЕЛЬНОМ ПАДЕЖЕ считается сравнением? Я тут вижу типичное обстоятельство образа действия, но никак не сравнение.

Comment: Потому что дым в настоящую змею не превращается, сравнивается со змеёй.

Comment: Не превращается, но взовьется он (каким образом) змеей, по-змеиному.

Comment: Ну вот тоже сравнение, только не такое отчётливое. Змеи по факту нет, поэтому считается сравнением с ней. Сравнить: *Вампир летучей мышью улетел.*

Comment: Спорный вопрос. Все же значения разные реализуются.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Обстоятельство — это [член предложения](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), сравнение — это [фигура речи](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8). Поэтому одно другому не мешает.

*Взовьется белый дым **змеей***.

*Змеей* — это сравнение, выраженное существительным в творительном падеже. Выполняет функцию обстоятельства, в котором на первый план выходит значение образа действия.

> [Виды сравнений:](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))
>
> - Сравнения в виде сравнительного оборота, образованного при помощи союзов *как, будто, словно, точно*: «Мужик глуп, как свинья, а хитёр, как чёрт».
> - Бессоюзные сравнения — в виде предложения с составным именным сказуемым: «Мой дом — моя крепость».
> - Сравнения, образованные при помощи существительного в творительном падеже: «он ходит гоголем».
> - Отрицающие сравнения: «Попытка не пытка».

А вот что у Розенталя в параграфе «[Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#)» (пункт 4):

> **Примечание:** <...> *Она ускользнёт, **как змея**, порхнёт и умчится, **как птичка***... автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения (*подобно змее, подобно птичке,* хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях *ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой,* но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).

Comment: Александр. Но ведь существует обстоятельство сравнения. Почему тогда "сравнением" считается совершенно другое обстоятельство  - образа действия (в данном случае), ведь у них разный функционал.

Comment: @МиМопи В вопросе смешаны разные категории из двух классификаций. [Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177): "В классификации обстоятельств по значению одним из восьми видов являются обстоятельства сравнения: они отвечают на вопрос КАК? и начинается с союзов КАК, СЛОВНО или БУДТО. Например: *У нее были длинные волосы, мягкие, как лен*. В некоторых учебниках и справочных пособиях обстоятельства сравнения называют также сравнительными оборотами. Необходимо запомнить, что **обстоятельства сравнения в предложениях выделяются запятыми**". Это, как я понимаю, "чистое" сравнение.

Comment: @МиМопи  Из Розенталя: "...на первый план выступает значениие обстоятельства образа действия (обороты с ***как*** можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием)".  Но сравнение как таковое (фигура, троп) никуда не исчезает, просто в обстоятельстве сильнее всего проявляется образ действия.

Comment: @МиМопи  Ещё вот что: в вопросе приведена цитата из правила, но на цитату не похоже. Проверьте, пожалуйста, этот момент.  Вы не видели мой комментарий под [этим ответом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472510/И-в-том-числе-спорный-случай-или-нет/472527#472527)?

Comment: Да. Перелистнул страницу, Розенталя не заметил. Теперь понятно, что значение "сравнения" просто ослабляется, но не уходит полностью.

Comment: @МиМопи  Интересно, а как выглядит полный вопрос в ОГЭ (может, с вариантами ответов)?

Comment: Вообще, обычно даются варианты. Но это пример из теоретической части.